# How to pass data from controller to js file in cakephp?

Tags: jquery, cakephp

```
jquery code

$("#pendingChart").sparkline([9, 11, 12, 13, 12, 13, 10], {
                type: 'bar',
                width: '100',
                barWidth: 6,
                height: '45',
                barColor: '#5C9BD1',
                negBarColor: '#e02222'
            });
```

This works fine and produce a graphical chart. But I want to produce the data [9, 11, 12, 13, 12, 13, 10] from controller and pass to the jquery code. My controller section is okay. Here is the code:

```
function loadPointChart() {
        $reseller = $this->Auth->user();
        if (count($reseller) > 0) {
            $api_key = $reseller['api_key'];
            $this->loadModel('Order');
            //  $info=$this->Order->find('all','conditions' => array('api_key'=>$api_key));

            $sql = "SELECT orders.id,orders.modified,orders.status,order_products.*  FROM orders
                LEFT JOIN order_products ON orders.id=order_products.order_id
                 WHERE orders.api_key = '$api_key' ORDER BY orders.modified ASC";

            $infos = $this->Order->query($sql);

            $return['points'] = $this->pointsCalculate($infos);

            $penaltyChart = json_encode($return['points']['penalty']);
            $pendingChart = json_encode($return['points']['pending']);
            $successChart = json_encode($return['points']['success']);
             echo $penaltyChart;
            $this->set(compact('penaltyChart'));
        }
    }
```

echo echo $penaltyChart; is printing exact format data which I need: `[4,3]`

But I would I manipulate this data into my jquery code.
I called this function inside before filter so that variable is initialized before page rendered.

to load data into jquery section I tried as follows:

```
$("#penaltyChart").sparkline(<?php echo $penaltyChart; ?>, {
                type: 'bar',
                width: '100',
                barWidth: 6,
                height: '45',
                barColor: '#F36A5B',
                negBarColor: '#e02222'
            });
```

It gives error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` . Any idea?

Comment: `It does not work` is not a proper problem description. What does the generated source look like? What does happen? What errors are thrown?

Comment: I edited My code. Thanks to point out my fault. It will help for next time to ask

Comment: did you inspect the page source code to see what the output looks like?

Comment: I just inspect the code and the php code is kept as plain text:   $("#penaltyChart").sparkline(<?php echo $penaltyChart; ?>, {

Comment: oh..there is no php compiling in a js file. You would need to pass a variable in a script tag and use that variable in your file. Or use ajax to get the data and call the plugin once the data is received

Comment: @AbdusSattarBhuiyan did you fix your problem? If not, did you tried my solutions to your problem? :)

Comment: I just applied your solution. It works.Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear good news from You today ( 13.11.2015 - Friday :D )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** In `load_point_chart.ctp:`

```
<script>$("#pendingChart").sparkline([<?php echo implode(",", $penaltyChart); ?>], {
            type: 'bar',
            width: '100',
            barWidth: 6,
            height: '45',
            barColor: '#5C9BD1',
            negBarColor: '#e02222'
        });</script>
```

**2.** or in `load_point_chart.ctp:`

```
echo "<script>$('#pendingChart').sparkline([" . implode(",", $penaltyChart) . "], {
        type: 'bar',
        width: '100',
        barWidth: 6,
        height: '45',
        barColor: '#5C9BD1',
        negBarColor: '#e02222'
    });</script>";
```

**3.** or in `load_point_chart.ctp` before loading the `.js` file:

```
<script>window.penaltyChart = [<?php echo implode(",", $penaltyChart); ?>]</script>
```

after this code include your `.js`, and then in your `.js` change the code like this:

```
$("#pendingChart").sparkline(window.penaltyChart, {
            type: 'bar',
            width: '100',
            barWidth: 6,
            height: '45',
            barColor: '#5C9BD1',
            negBarColor: '#e02222'
        });
```